# Как создать такую вложенность массива из имеющегося массива?

Tags: php

У меня есть массив вида:

> array( 0 => 'one', 1 => 'two', 2 => 'three', 3 => 'four' )

Мне нужно из него создать объект (json_encode) чтобы он был такого вида:

> [["one","two"],["three","four"]]

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: php.net/array_chunk

Comment: @Ипатьев если оформите это в более развернутый ответ - я отмечу его. Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: В таком виде этому вопросу ответ не нужен. Если вы сформулируете нормальный заголовок, который отражает суть вопроса, то можете добавить ответ. Тогда он пригодится кому-то ещё.